# Parallax scrolling: Unwanted gap in between layers

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, parallax

On my website [here](http://www.reynelee.com), I implemented multi-layered parallax scrolling with CSS and Javascript. The page scrolls up and down, and I have 6 layers all moving in parallax. Each layer going back scrolls at a slightly slower speed than the layer in front.

This implementation works until I click on the hamburger menu in the top right corner.

[Image of the Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAjZV.png)

I'm not sure why the layers are not stacked on top of each other properly once the slide menu flies out.

Here is the CSS for the parallax scrolling:

```
.layer {
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

.layer-bg {
  background-image: url("http://www.reynelee.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/layer1.png");
}

.layer-1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.reynelee.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/layer2.png\a     ");
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.layer-2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.reynelee.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/layer3.png");
}

.layer-3 {
  background-image: url("http://www.reynelee.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/layer4.png\a    ");
  background-position: right bottom;
}
```

And here is the JS:

```
(function() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    var depth, i, layer, layers, len, movement, topDistance, translate3d;
    topDistance = this.pageYOffset;
    layers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-type='parallax']");
    for (i = 0, len = layers.length; i < len; i++) {
      layer = layers[i];
      depth = layer.getAttribute('data-depth');
      movement = -(topDistance * depth);
      translate3d = 'translate3d(0, ' + movement + 'px, 0)';
      layer.style['-webkit-transform'] = translate3d;
      layer.style['-moz-transform'] = translate3d;
      layer.style['-ms-transform'] = translate3d;
      layer.style['-o-transform'] = translate3d;
      layer.style.transform = translate3d;
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

HTML:

```
<div id='hero'>
  <div class='layer-bg layer' data-depth='0.10' data-type='parallax'></div>
  <div class='layer-1 layer' data-depth='0.20' data-type='parallax'></div>
  <div class='layer-2 layer' data-depth='0.50' data-type='parallax'></div>
  <div class='layer-3 layer' data-depth='0.80' data-type='parallax'></div>
  <div class='layer-overlay layer' data-depth='0.85' data-type='parallax'></div>
<!--   <div class='layer-4 layer' data-depth='0.90' data-type='parallax'></div> -->
  <div class='layer-logo layer' data-depth='0.95' data-type='parallax'> <a id='portfolio-button' href="http://www.reynelee.com/my-work/">View Work</a></div> <!-- my logo-->
<!--   <div class='layer-close layer' data-depth='1.00' data-type='parallax'></div> -->

</div>
```

Comment: I would start by `console.log` all the variables before the for loop, to see if something changes when the menu is extended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the transform css property. For example if you apply the following rule:

```
#page {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

You will notice it causes the same problem without the menu open. I've run into this before and I forget the actual name of the term, but applying transform causes the browser to treat it differently in some way. My recommendation is to apply this `translateX(0)` on the #page element, and recalculate the positions of your parallax divs based on this default position. I know this is not a complete answer but it should get you going.